# Zend gotoUrlAndExit VS gotoUrl

Tags: php, zend-framework

I want to know the difference between these two Zend redirector functions. Obviously when I call `gotoUrl` it redirect me to new page and rest of the code will not execute like

```
   ... Some Code  // This will execute 

   $redirector->gotoUrl('bamboo/jamboo') ;  // Page will redirect to jamboo and reset of code will not execute.

   ... Some Code  // This will not execute as we already redirect to new page.
```

Why to exit after redirection? What does it make sense? any idea?

Answer (score 2):

That's a pretty common misconception about how redirection works.

When you call `gotoUrl`, you are sending a message to the browser "go to this URL I'm giving you right now", but the rest of the script on the page continues to run (and you can still send more information to the browser while the script runs). This actually can cause some [truly epic destruction](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/WellIntentioned-Destruction.aspx).

On the other hand, `gotoUrlAndExit` tells the browser the same thing, but it prevents any further code execution.

Many times the two functions will have the same behavior, but it pays to know the difference.

Comment: is that means that you have to put die or exit after redirect???? if we do without zend framework

Comment: Yes. `header` does not stop script execution, it simply adds an HTTP header to the top.